# Java - How to test if an exception was thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to test in another function if findByElem throws an exception?
For example main calls findByElem, how can I test if the exception was thrown (without findByElem re-throwing the exception)?

```
 public TNode findByElem(T _elem) {
        LLNode<T> node = root;

        while (node != null && node.elem.compareTo(_elem) < 0) {
            node = node.next;
        }

        if (node == null || node.elem.compareTo(_elem) != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Node "+_elem.toString() + " could not be found in linked list");
        }
    return node.ptr;

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - `findElem` wouldn't need to "rethrow" the exception - it's already throwing it...

Comment: How would you cath it in the outer loop(ex. in main)?

Comment: Um, you would just use a catch block. Although catching RuntimeException is generally a bad idea.

Comment: You can throw own custom exception instead of using the standard exception.

Comment: Sorry, dumb question...